# How to find percentage in a report card in Python?

Tags: python

Please guide me; I want to print percentage of the three subjects. The program I made is:

```
subjects = ["Maths","English","Science"]
names = ["Talha","Fazeel","Usayd","Mujtuba","Sufyan","Aukasha","Moiz","Mohid","Wasil"]
scores = [[10,8,7],[8,8,6],[7,5,4],[4,0,2],[3,9,4],[7,8,3],[8,7,5],[9,5,7],[8,7,9]]
a=0
while a<len(names):
    highest=scores[a][0]
    subject=subjects[0]
    i=0
    while i<=2:
        if scores[a][i]>highest:
            highest=scores[a][i]
            subject=subjects[i]
        i=i+1
        

    print(names[a]+"'s Highest in",subject+":", highest)
    a=a+1
```

I can't understand how to find percentage in this program. Please tell me what to add and where to add?
My expected output is:

```
Talha's Highest in Maths: 10 and percentage is: 83.4%
Fazeel's Highest in Maths: 8 and percentage is: 73.34%
Usayd's Highest in Maths: 7 and percentage is: 53.34%
Mujtuba's Highest in Maths: 4 and percentage is: 20%
Sufyan's Highest in English: 9 and percentage is: 53.34%
Aukasha's Highest in English: 8 and percentage is: 60%
Moiz's Highest in Maths: 8 and percentage is: 66.67%
Mohid's Highest in Maths: 9 and percentage is: 70%
Wasil's Highest in Science: 9 and percentage is: 80%
```

Comment: What does the percentage represent? Based on your data, Talha scored a 10 in Math, so how are you coming up with 83.4%?

Comment: look at the arrays they are representing total 3 subject marks, the percentage is of those three subjects.

Comment: Calculate a simple average based on the items in `scores[a]`. It's pretty straightforward - just add the items and divide by the length of subjects, or 3 in this case.

Comment: I just can't understand where to put this in the code?

Comment: Below is the code, look once and let me know if any issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of ways you can improve your code by using prebuild function or methods provided by python.

```
subjects = ["Maths", "English", "Science"]
names = ["Talha", "Fazeel", "Usayd", "Mujtuba", "Sufyan", "Aukasha", "Moiz", "Mohid", "Wasil"]
scores = [[10, 8, 7], [8, 8, 6], [7, 5, 4], [4, 0, 2], [3, 9, 4], [7, 8, 3], [8, 7, 5], [9, 5, 7], [8, 7, 9]]
a = 0
while a < len(names):
    h_marks = (max(scores[a]))
    subject = subjects[scores[a].index(h_marks)]
    percentage = round(sum(scores[a])/30*100, 2)
    print(f"{names[a]}'s Highest in {subject}: {h_marks} and percentage is: {percentage}%")
    a = a+1
```

In this code

1. max(list) will return you maximum value from the list.
2. list.index(x) will returns index of "x" in list "list".
3. round(x,y) will round your float number "x" with "y" numbers of decimal digits.
4. f"Value of x: {x}" is called *string formatting* which places the value of x in the string while creating and initializing the string.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i'm a beginner and can't understand a single thing u did in your code.-_-

Comment: Good answer! It'd be even better if you added links to documentation for each of the points for further reading for OP. Another pythonization: use `zip` to iterate over `names` and `scores` instead of `while`

Comment: @Sara, Please find a few explanations about the changes and new functions or methods used in this code and how can they be applied in general.
and I totally agree with the suggestion given by@PranavHosangadi, This code can definitely be optimized and well wrote, but assuming Sara is fairly new to python, that's why the basic modification is done on code to understand the code better.

Comment: ok no problem @MdZafarHassan. I would surely try to learn about new functions sooner :)

Answer (score 1):

As we you need total marks of every student so you can sum of at every iteration of inner loop. Once total value is get of 3 subjects.

After getting total you can count percentage.

Here is the updated code

```
subjects = ["Maths","English","Science"]
names = ["Talha","Fazeel","Usayd","Mujtuba","Sufyan","Aukasha","Moiz","Mohid","Wasil"]
scores = [[10,8,7],[8,8,6],[7,5,4],[4,0,2],[3,9,4],[7,8,3],[8,7,5],[9,5,7],[8,7,9]]
a=0
while a<len(names):
    highest=scores[a][0]
    subject=subjects[0]
    i=0
    total = 0
    while i<=2:
        total += scores[a][i]
        if scores[a][i]>highest:
            highest=scores[a][i]
            subject=subjects[i]
        i=i+1
        percentage = str("{:.2f}".format(total/30*100)) 
    print(names[a]+"'s Highest in",str(subject)+":", str(highest)+" and percetnage is ", percentage)
    a=a+1
```

OUTPUT:

```
Talha's Highest in Maths: 10 and percetnage is  83.33                                                                         
Fazeel's Highest in Maths: 8 and percetnage is  73.33                                                                         
Usayd's Highest in Maths: 7 and percetnage is  53.33                                                                          
Mujtuba's Highest in Maths: 4 and percetnage is  20.00                                                                        
Sufyan's Highest in English: 9 and percetnage is  53.33                                                                       
Aukasha's Highest in English: 8 and percetnage is  60.00                                                                      
Moiz's Highest in Maths: 8 and percetnage is  66.67                                                                           
Mohid's Highest in Maths: 9 and percetnage is  70.00                                                                          
Wasil's Highest in Science: 9 and percetnage is  80.00                                                                        
                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                              
...Program finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. This is especially applicable when OP is a beginner and trying to understand why their code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm actually a beginner and this answer helped me so u should not devote it@PranavHosangadi

Comment: @VishalSheth can u please simplify it more further..

Comment: In which way, like do you want to optimize the code. If so I can suggest figure out the constant variable and changeable variable. If you don't understand please let me know.          Thanks

Comment: I can't understand this line: percentage = str("{:.2f}".format(total/30*100))

Comment: To get 2 digit after floating point.   Reference Link : https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-print-a-float-with-two-decimal-places-in-python#:~:text=Use%20str.,float%20with%20two%20decimal%20places&text=2f%7D%22%20as%20str%20and%20a,string%20to%20print%20the%20float.